# How to flush job output in vim8?

Tags: vimscript, job-control

Trying to do something with job output in `exit_cb` or `close_cb`, but it's all buffered, how to flush it. e.g.:

```
function! s:exit_cb(job, status)
  echom getbufline(s:bufnr, '$')
endfunction

function! s:close_cb(channel)
  echom getbufline(s:bufnr, '$')
endfunction

let s:bufnr = term_start('seq 1000',
      \ {'exit_cb': function("s:exit_cb"), 'close_cb':function("s:close_cb") })
```

None of them echo `1000`,  how to flush it ?

One work around is to call `:h :sleep`, but i don't think that's the right way.

**update**

As [B Layer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/11054/b-layer) pointed out, result of `close_cb` depends on terminal window height. e.g., if it's height is 30, it prints `971`, as `971 = 1000 - 30 + 1`.

I reread `:h close_cb` , it says:

> Vim will invoke callbacks that handle data before invoking
>           close_cb, thus when this function is called no more data will
>           be passed to the callbacks.

I guess the callback vim invoked to handle data haven't finished by the time `close_cb` is called. Tried to call `term_wait()` in `close_cb`, but it cause hang.

**update**

A similar [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1320) on github.

Comment: How do you know it's being buffered? What are you observing exactly? Did you strace it? BTW, there's no guarantee they'd echo 1000 even if things weren't "stuck"...could be 782,. :)

Comment: `:h job-exit_cb` Says `data can be buffered`,  i guess the same thing happen for `job-close_cb`.  I havn't straced it. I will try it later.

Comment: @BLayer Why it could be 782 even if things weren't "stuck" ?

Comment: That's a typo, I meant to write 982. Back to that in a minute...something strange is going on. I was curious to see if I could reproduce your hang so I rather quickly entered something close to your code and ran it. No hang. Just saw that one of the callbacks prints the first line of the term buffer and that is wholly dependent on window heights (I saw 977 and 982). BUT now I realize that you're asking, properly as far as I can see, for the last line so I should be getting 1000. D'oh! Maybe I fat fingered something...forget I mentioned it! :D

Comment: @BLayer You are right about window height. I think vim alread read all the data from `channel` in `exit_cb`, but it havn't finished updating it. See update.

Comment: Interesting. I need to learn more about this particular topic.