# Running make from vim

Tags: makeprg

I would like to use vim as a c++ IDE. Is there a possibility to run "make" and see the "make" progression in a separate (newly opened) pane. Also, the consecutive execution of the binary would be nice.

Comment: If you use tmux your available options grow somewhat. (If you don't use tmux you should check it out....even if you don't use it for the above purposes.)

Comment: Try `term make` ,  if you need `quickfix`, execute `cgetbuffer` from the terminal buffer later. To be honest, I prefer the colored raw `make` output. The  `quickfix` for `make` result of `c++` looks awful to me.

Comment: Personally, I found C++ external compilation to be a PITA. Some silly mistake (like forgetting to define stream operators) are quick to generate hundred of useless messages. That's why I found that the best user experience is achieved with integrated compilation -- which could is synchronous (default), or could be make asynchronous (with plugins). Can't we use [Christian's plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/Colorizer) to highlight in qf windows the coloured make outputs?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Vim has the built in `:make` command which executes `make` by default, but you can set up other build systems by setting `makeprg`. There’s no progress visualisation by default, but once `:make` is done you can move through errors an earnings encountered with `:cnext` and `:cprev`. Calling `:copen` will show you all of them.

One disadvantage though is that `:make` is synchronous so your Vim instance will be blocked until compilation finish. There are plugins like [Neomake](https://github.com/neomake/neomake) that implement similar functionality using the asynchronous API.

There’s no default way to run your compiled program, but you can define a custom mapping or command to run it after compilation

Comment: [vim-makejob](https://git.danielmoch.com/vim-makejob/log.html) is another alternative for async `:make`.

Comment: A further alternative would be [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) which provides an async `:Make` command. I have written an answer describing vim-dispatch for another question which might offer some bits for the OP as well: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22432/1292

Comment: Or my [build-tools-wrappers](https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/auto-detect-build-dirs/doc/make_run.md) that does much more for C++ (e.g. it supports multiple build directories: debug, release, sanatize, whatever...). There are indeed many solutions.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of vim `terminal` in vim 8.0 and later to handle asynchronous jobs.

Thus, to launch `make` in a vertical split, you can do:

```
:vertical terminal make
```

I have a small function (with a command) to do exactly this:

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>)
function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline) abort
    exe 'vert terminal '. a:cmdline
endfunction
```

So you can do `:Shell any_command` to launch a command in a vertical split (i.e `:Shell find /`).

For `make` specifically, I use it in conjunction with those mappings:

```
nnoremap <leader>csm :Shell make<cr><cr>
nnoremap <leader>csr :Shell make re<cr><cr>
nnoremap <leader>cst :Shell make ex<cr><cr>
```

`ex` is a rule in my Makefile that launches my tests.

One caveat is that `make` rules auto-completion does not work.

Answer (score 1):

#### Throw away make

`make` is synchronous, that's it, just throw it away.

#### Async tool

One can use [:h :terminal](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#%3Aterminal)  or [:h term_start()](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#term_start%28%29) to do async stuff in `vim`.
We will use `term_start` here as the basic async tool.

#### Goal

- Async make, update `quickfix` after it, user should see the making progress just like make in terminal.
- Show `make successful` message if no error, no warning happens.
- Show `found n qf entries` if there exists `quickfix` entry with specific buffer number and line number.
- Toggle making buffer if user request `make` again during `making`.
- Spawn new make, delete last making buffer if user request `make` during `idle`.

#### Interface

```
nnoremap <f7> :Make<cr>
command -nargs=* Make call s:make(<q-args>)
```

#### Spawn async job

```
let s:making = 0

function s:make(args) abort

  if s:making
    if bufwinid(s:make_buf) == -1
      " show making buffer
      exe 'sbuffer' s:make_buf
      wincmd p
    else
      " hide making buffer
      exe printf('%d wincmd q', bufwinnr(s:make_buf))
    endif
    return
  endif

  " delete last result
  if exists('s:make_buf') && bufexists(s:make_buf)
    silent! exe 'bdelete' s:make_buf
  endif

  " spawn new make
  let cmd = 'make'
  if !empty(a:args)
    let cmd .= ' ' . a:args
  endif

  let options = {'close_cb': function('s:make_callback'), 'term_rows': 16}

  let s:make_buf = term_start(cmd, options)
  let s:making = 1

  wincmd p

endfunction
```

#### The subtle handler

```
func s:make_callback(channel)

  " look, you can not get buffer content directly here.
  call timer_start(10, function('s:make_callback_impl'))
endfunction

function s:make_callback_impl(timer) abort

  exe 'cgetbuffer' s:make_buf

  " consider entry with num zero bufnr and lnum an error or warning
  let qfl = filter(getqflist(), {k,v -> v.bufnr != 0 && v.lnum != 0})

  if empty(qfl)
    echo "make successful"
  else
    echohl WarningMsg
    echom printf('found %d qf entries', len(qfl))
    echohl None
  endif

  let s:making = 0

endfunction
```

Be careful here, one might try to get buffer directly at `s:make_callback`, that won't work, see
 [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20402/how-to-flush-job-output-in-vim8) for detail.

Comment: At this point, why not just use Dispatch?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble It's a small task, I prefer to do it by myself with built in async tool.